# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' python

Tags: python

I have a problem with Python.
This is my code:

```
def calcola():
            a = input()
            b = float(a[0].split("*"))
            c = float(a[0].split("/")) 
            d = float(a[0].split("-"))
            e = float(a[0].split("+"))
            j = float(a[1].split("*"))
            k = float(a[1].split("/")) 
            l = float(a[1].split("-")) 
            m = float(a[1].split("+")) 
            b = b[0]
            c = b[1]
            d = c[0]
            e = c[1]
            f = d[0]
            g = d[1]
            h = e[0]
            i = e[1]
            somma1 = b+c
            somma2 = d+e
            somma3 = f+g
            somma4 = h+i
            print(somma1)
            print(somma2)
            print(somma3)
            print(somma4)


calcola()
```

I've recieved some errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "file.py", line 29, in 
>      calcola()
>    File "file.py", line 3, in calcola
>      b = float(a[0].split("*"))
>   TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

How can I transform the number in the list?

Comment: `split` splits a string into a list and you can't transform a list into a float. How does `a` and `a[0]` look like?

Comment: so, I must use b = float(a)?

Comment: my input is a = input()

Comment: Give an example of what you expect the user to type in as input. Even better, show us the input which is giving you an error.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You're splitting the same input on different punctutation characters, and expect to be able to convert it to a float in each case. If the input is `1*2+3`, when you do `split("*")` the two parts will be `1` and `2+3`. You can convert `1` to a float, but you can't convert `2+3` to a float. You'll have the opposite problem when you do `split("+")`.

Comment: Also, you're first setting `c = float(a[0].split("/"))` but later you do `c = b[1]`. Try using more meaningful variable names so you don't reuse them by accident.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't call `float` on a list directly. You can use `map` to call `float` on each item in the list. Like so:

```
b = map(float, a[0].split("*"))
```

In python 3.x

```
b = list(map(float, a[0].split("*")))
```

Or for more readability, use a list comprehension. Works for both python2 and python3:

```
b = [float(s) for s in a[0].split("*")]
```

But be sure the items after splitting are *floatable*

Comment: Better to use a list comprehension.

Comment: Usually, yes. But with builtins like `float` map does it faster.

Comment: Speed is not a concern here. Beware of premature optimization. Readability makes comprehensions and generators are much more idiomatic. In this case OP is obviously a novice, making readability that much more important.

Comment: @machineyearning Ok. I'll add a list comprehension variant