# Decimal with exponential

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a list like this:

```
a = ['4.2332e-9']
```

I think the number is a string here and I need it as a number. If I try:

```
a1 = float(a)
```

I get an error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number.
```

If I try:

```
a1 = Decimal(a)
```

I also get an error:

```
Invalid tuple size in creation of Decimal from list or tuple. The list or tuple should have exactly three elements.
```

Any ideas of how I can solve it?

Comment: You have a list of strings, not a string. `float` expects a string, so do `float(a[0])`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629828/typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-list-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = ['4.2332e-9', '-8', '5.7', '6.423', '-5', '-6.77', '10']
print map(float, lst)
```

Comment: Python version 2.x

Comment: Done! Sorry, I'm new here, I didnt know I had to do it hehe :)