# How to convert a list in a float?

Tags: python

My code has the following error: float () argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'.

I know that my ww function is a list of values, but I do not know how to convert it to float, since ww is a function. I tried list comprehension, following the question in:

[TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629828/typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-list-python)

But it didn't work.

```
def func(n):
    return 2/(n+1)

def ww(n):
    return [-1 + i*func(n) for i in range(0,n+1)] 

def g(x,y):
    return x**2 + y
```

This g(x,y) is actually spherical harmonics, but I put this for simplicity.

```
def integral(n):
    return [np.pi*func(n)*(1 + math.cos(np.pi*(-1 + i*func(n))))*g(np.pi*i,ww(n)) for i in range(0,n+1)]
```

Comment: Can you explain what `ww` is supposed to do?

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: Try removing the square brackets.

Comment: Can you paste traceback?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do, but wrapping the return of `ww` into a numpy array would allow the calculation to continue (whether it is correct or not is another matter), e.g. `return np.array([-1 + i*func(n) for i in range(0,n+1)])`

Comment: ww is the argument of the function g, in case of spherical harmonics it will be the $\theta$.

Comment: If I remove the square brackets returns "invalid syntax"

Comment: The np.array works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ww` function returns a list of floats, which are then passed into `g()`. The calculation fails because you cannot add a `list` to a number.

It is not possible to "convert a list of floats to a float" without performing some sort of operation on the numbers — e.g. "add", "subtract", "multiply".

However, you can convert the list to an numpy array, which can be operated on as a whole. Multiplying an array of numbers by a single number multiplies each value, returning the result.

For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
>>> b = 2
>>> b ** 2 + a
array([5.0, 6.0, 7.0])
```

If you wrap the return value of `ww` to convert to a numpy array, the subsequent calculation in `g()` should work.

```
def ww(n):
    return np.array([-1 + i*func(n) for i in range(0,n+1)])
```